# How to display data from database?

Tags: php, mysql, database

I'm making shopping cart, and I have s problem displaying the products. Here's a part of the code where I think the problem is. I'm using xampp. Is something wrong with the query? Please help, Thanks

```
<?php
include("includes/db.php");
include("includes/functions.php");

if($_REQUEST['command']=='add' && $_REQUEST['productid']>0){
    $pid=$_REQUEST['productid'];
    addtocart($pid,1);
    header("location:shoppingcart.php");
    exit();
}
     ?>
 <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"     "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
  <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
   <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" / >
   <title>Products</title> 
   <script language="javascript">
function addtocart(pid){
    document.form1.productid.value=pid;
    document.form1.command.value='add';
    document.form1.submit();
 }
   </script>
   </head>


   <body>
     <form name="form1">
<input type="hidden" name="productid" />
   <input type="hidden" name="command" />
    </form>
   <div align="center">
<h1 align="center">Products</h1>
<table border="0" cellpadding="2px" width="600px">
   <?
    $result=mysql_query("select * from products");
    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
   ?>
   <tr>
    <td><img src="<?php echo $row['picture']; ?>" /></td>
    <td>    <b><?php echo $row['name']; ?></b><br />
            <?php echo $row['description']; ?><br />
            Price:<big style="color:green">
                $<?php echo $row['price']; ?></big><br /><br />
            <input type="button" value="Add to Cart" onclick="addtocart(<?php echo         $row['serial']?>)" />
     </td>
   </tr>
   <tr><td colspan="2"><hr size="1" /></td>
   <? } ?>
  </table>
  < /div>
   </body>
  </html>
```

[edit]
Here's the db.php that is included in the script from above:

```
<?
@mysql_connect("localhost","root","") or die("Cannot connect");
@mysql_select_db("shopping") or die("Cannot connect");
session_start();
?>
```

And here is the functions.php also included in the script from the above code:

```
<?
function get_product_name($pid){
    $result=mysql_query("select name from products where serial=$pid");
    $row=mysql_fetch_array($result);
    return $row['name'];
}
function get_price($pid){
    $result=mysql_query("select price from products where serial=$pid");
    $row=mysql_fetch_array($result);
    return $row['price'];
}
function remove_product($pid){
    $pid=intval($pid);
    $max=count($_SESSION['cart']);
    for($i=0;$i<$max;$i++){
        if($pid==$_SESSION['cart'][$i]['productid']){
            unset($_SESSION['cart'][$i]);
            break;
        }
    }
    $_SESSION['cart']=array_values($_SESSION['cart']);
}
function get_order_total(){
    $max=count($_SESSION['cart']);
    $sum=0;
    for($i=0;$i<$max;$i++){
        $pid=$_SESSION['cart'][$i]['productid'];
        $q=$_SESSION['cart'][$i]['qty'];
        $price=get_price($pid);
        $sum+=$price*$q;
    }
    return $sum;
}
function addtocart($pid,$q){
    if($pid<1 or $q<1) return;

    if(is_array($_SESSION['cart'])){
        if(product_exists($pid)) return;
        $max=count($_SESSION['cart']);
        $_SESSION['cart'][$max]['productid']=$pid;
        $_SESSION['cart'][$max]['qty']=$q;
    }
    else{
        $_SESSION['cart']=array();
        $_SESSION['cart'][0]['productid']=$pid;
        $_SESSION['cart'][0]['qty']=$q;
    }
}
function product_exists($pid){
    $pid=intval($pid);
    $max=count($_SESSION['cart']);
    $flag=0;
    for($i=0;$i<$max;$i++){
        if($pid==$_SESSION['cart'][$i]['productid']){
            $flag=1;
            break;
        }
    }
    return $flag;
}

  ?>
```

The products table:

```
 CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `products` (
  `serial` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `name` varchar(20) collate latin1_general_ci NOT NULL,
  `description` varchar(255) collate latin1_general_ci NOT NULL,
  `price` float NOT NULL,
  `picture` varchar(80) collate latin1_general_ci NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY  (`serial`)
  ) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 COLLATE=latin1_general_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=7 ;

 INSERT INTO `products` (`serial`, `name`, `description`, `price`, `picture`) VALUES
 (1, 'View Sonic LCD', '19" View Sonic Black LCD, with 10 months warranty', 250,   'images/lcd.jpg'),
 (2, 'IBM CDROM Drive', 'IBM CDROM Drive', 80, 'images/cdrom-drive.jpg'),
 (3, 'Laptop Charger', 'Dell Laptop Charger with 6 months warranty', 50, 'images/charger.jpg'),
 (4, 'Seagate Hard Drive', '80 GB Seagate Hard Drive in 10 months warranty', 40, 'images/hard-drive.jpg'),
 (5, 'Atech Mouse', 'Black colored laser mouse. No warranty', 5, 'images/mouse.jpg');
```

Comment: `<?php=$row['picture']?>` should be `<?=$row['picture']?>`

Comment: Just to be sure because it's not in the code you posted, you're connected to the database and to the table?

Comment: Please actually define your problem. What do you expect and what's the actual output?

Comment: It should display the products from the database, such as the price, name and description along with an image. When i enter var_dump($row) it displays NULL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your echo shorthand depends on server config. Try the following to see if that works, I usually stray away from [short tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/200640/are-php-short-tags-acceptable-to-use)

```
<table border="0" cellpadding="2px" width="600px">
    <?php
        $result=mysql_query("select * from products");
        while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    ?>
    <tr>
        <td><img src="<?php echo $row['picture']; ?>" /></td>
        <td>    <b><?php echo $row['name']; ?></b><br />
                <?php echo $row['description']; ?><br />
                Price:<big style="color:green">
                    $<?php echo $row['price']; ?></big><br /><br />
                <input type="button" value="Add to Cart"   onclick="window.location='shoppingcart.php'" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr><td colspan="2"><hr size="1" /></td>
    <?php } ?>
</table>
```

Comment: Make sure your errors are turned on. Can you verify there is data in the `products` table? Is it outputting anything?

Comment: It only outputs: Price: and the button Add To Cart.

Comment: what does your `products` table look like?

Comment: That may not be the spot in your code with the problem then because it would work if you are connected to the database properly and able to query that table. View the source of the webpage to see if there are any errors. Remove the `@` from `mysql_connect` and `mysql_select_db`.

Comment: Ans how can I view the source?

Comment: I did it and it shows the scripts. I edited the whole script products.php above.

Comment: Paste the source youre seeing to pastebin.com and provide the link.

Comment: @Isabella, the solution provided by @Aaronw seems correct. Though you have replaced `<?=` with `<?php echo` but your code is still using the short tags `<?`. Please replace all short tags `<?` with `<?php` and you should get it running

Comment: OK i changed it, but now it gives me this error:Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\SHOPPINGCART\products.php on line 37

Comment: That means your `$result` has a problem. Try `$result=mysql_query("select * from products") or die(mysql_error());`

Comment: It says "No database selected".Was selected in db.php

Comment: Remove the `@` from `mysql_select_db`

Comment: It is because you are using short tags in db.php. Change them to <?php in it and all other PHP scripts

Comment: Thank you AaronW and Abhay and I'm sorry for wasting your time ;) Finally it works!

Comment: No problem, we are happy to help. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

```
 <table border="0" cellpadding="2px" width="600px">
        <?php
            $result=mysql_query("select * from products");
            while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
        ?>
        <tr>
            <td><img src="<?php echo $row['picture'] ?>" />
            </td>
            <td>    <b><?php echo $row['name'] ?></b><br />
                    <?php echo $row['description'] ?><br />
                    Price:<big style="color:green">
                    $<?php echo $row['price'] ?></big><br /><br />
                    <input type="button" value="Add to Cart"  onclick="addtocart(<?php echo $row['serial']?>)" /></td>
        </tr>
        <?php } ?>
      </table>
```